# How to change the default dotted border of any clickable html control

Tags: html, css

I am working on an HTML page with few tab and click-able div which toggle between controls. But each control when click show dotted background as show in image below

[image]

How can i change this to any other color or not show it at all

Comment: could you send us code in addition to picture?

Comment: or it has to do something with focus

Comment: Note that this might cause some issues: https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

Comment: I resolved it with following css `a:focus {
  outline: none;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `outline:none;` for click-able div

Answer (score 0):

your dotted must befined by something like this:

```
p {
    border-style: dotted solid;
    color:yellow;
}
```

you can put this if you want to remove it:

```
p {
    border-style: none;
}
```

or change the type of dot:

```
p {
    border-style: dashed solid;
}
```